# How come SPPlaylistFolder doesn't conform to SPAsyncLoading?

Tags: cocoalibspotify-2.0

I'm using CocoaLibSpotify 2.0 for my app.

With the 2.0 version of CLS, a bunch of objects conform to the `SPAsyncLoading` protocol, allowing you to use ´-waitUntilLoaded:...´. But `SPPlaylistFolder` doesn't conform to the protocol – does that mean that all its metadata is loaded as soon as I get hold of the instance or do I have to use KVO on its properties?

Is there a reason as to why `SPPlaylistFolder` doesn't conform to the `SPAsyncLoading` protocol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `SPPlaylistFolder`, it's been loaded — due to various boring implementation details, folder metadata is loaded alongside `SPPlaylistContainer`, so as soon as that's loaded and you can access folders, folder metadata has already completed loading.